# Entity framework code first: why is my collection not created?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first

I have some class called myDB that inherits from DbContext
the class contains the following member :

```
public DbSet<Zoo> mAllZoos { get; set; }
```

the Zoo class looks like this :

```
public class Zoo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public int ZooSize { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

there is an "Animal" class which is not relevant at all, but it does contain "ID".

when i ask him to create a Database from my classes he creates a Table named Animal for my animals, and a table Zoo for my zoos..

In the zoo table, there are only "Size" and "Name" fields
And in the animal table there are ID and other properties but no reference to the Zoo.

The bottom line is that there is no reference from the animals to the zoos , so i can't save which animal is in which zoo ..

What did i do wrong ? And how do i fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to declare an Animal `DbSet` in your context as well

```
public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
```

Does the animal class have an ID property or at least a property marked with the `KeyAttribute`? Entity Framework will use that ID (or key) to create the `Foreign Key` relation between the tables.

By the way, you'll have to mark the `Animals` property in the `Zoo` class as `virtual` if you want Lazy Loading to work:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
```